# Get TransactionID from Recurring Profile Information

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

I have created ReurringPaymentProfile using CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API and can get all details of the profile using GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails API.But now i want make function by which site admin can refund any amount of any transaction.

I have already worked with RefundTrasaction API but that is with Ecommerce.But for RefundTrasaction we need TransactionID but in recuruing payment i have not get the tansction id.

Can any one help to get the transction id for RefundTRansction API. Or How i will refund the subscription Money using API.

Thanking you all

Comment: how did you create recurring profile, could you please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link .

It give step by step description about creating recurring profile.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/